# eth_accounts RPC method returns some unexpected accounts on the Fantom blockchain

Tags: json-rpc, rpc, fantom

What are the accounts that get returned by the eth_accounts RPC call on the Fantom blockchain? This doesn't seem to be the case on other blockchains and they (seemingly) always return an empty list.

Here is an example result with CURL. The request:

```
$ curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_accounts","params":[],"id":67}' https://rpc.ftm.tools/
```

and the response:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":67,"result":["0xbaa007aa9d31cf14b16a7ae30d9fe496eb58d32d","0x5a7d43f0f9c9e894e7af0606fa92a3364da9de4f","0x35301a193dbe160ee56d7417cbb6a3090804bce8","0xf1df0baa1255ce3f42e4de579e2f5db759111888","0xfa92df4266eaf65c3e5b621587166ec39481b057","0xc2a641a4e23c725ba17c4e40891ed614d58f3e27"]}%
```

Answer (score 1):

As it seems, these are probably the addresses owned by the RPC node. They change because I probably constantly hit different actual nodes behind the loadbalancer